# Redirect home page with example.com// in magento 2

Tags: magento2, redirect

Hello I just Moved My Website and I am getting Error in home page page is not redirect properly Home page is open with 2 slash www.example.com//

Comment: please check entry in core_config_table for `base_url`.

Comment: There were // in table .right ?